# Using .map() method to render array items into their own separate divs, but comma is still displaying?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I've searched and searched but I've only found solutions to .join() the items into a single string..

```
const createCard = () => {
    const pokemonTypes = ['grass', 'fire', 'water'];
      return (
        `<div>
          ${pokemonTypes.map(type => `<div>${type}</div>`)}
        </div>`
      )
}

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", createCard());
```

For some context, I am using an API but I simplified the code so it's quick and easy to read.

I am trying to display each string into its own div so that I can style each div separately...like color coded buttons: green for grass, blue for water, red for fire etc.

When I run the code the strings successfully display in their own div, however the comma remains. I'd like them to just display next to each without the comma separating them.

Comment: `document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", createCard().join(''));`

Comment: "*I've only found solutions to .join() the items into a single string*" - so why don't you do that?

Comment: Wow I was making that harder than it needed to be..it didn't even occur to me that .map returned an array of the HTML strings, rather than just the strings of the original array

Comment: Thank you to everyone who answered. I'm still getting familiar with all of these array methods. I was overthinking too much and it was silly for me to ask this question. My apologies if I wasted your time. A lesson to be learned, I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.map` returns an array as the output. Setting this array as the html content is same as casting an array to a string.

**Example**

```js
const numArray = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(numArray.toString());
```

Casting an array to a string will always includes the comma in between.

Your expression is same as below one

```js
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", [1, 2, 3]);
```

What you have to do is you have to join this array with empty string and set this single string as the html contant as below.

Use `.join('')` to join an array without comma

```js
const createCard = () => {
  const pokemonTypes = ['grass', 'fire', 'water'];
  return (
    `<div>
      ${pokemonTypes.map(type => `<div>${type}</div>`).join('')}
    </div>`
  );
}

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", createCard());
```

Comment: Thank you! I need to practice these array methods..It didn't occur to me that .map returned an array of the HTML div strings..which could be concatenated with .join()

Comment: My apologies, I meant to approve your answer. I was flustered because I realize it was silly for me to ask this question in the first place

Answer (score 1):

The `.map()` method returns an array. In the template literal `` `${}` `` js will convert this array to a string. It does that by default by joining the elements with comma's. You can join the array to a string yourself without a comma:

```
${pokemonTypes.map(type => `<div>${type}</div>`).join('')}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.join('')` for string concrete and the same type used for styling.

```js
const createCard = () => {
  const pokemonTypes = ['grass', 'fire', 'water'];
  return (
    `<div>
      ${pokemonTypes.map(type => `<div class="${type}">${type}</div>`).join('')}
    </div>`
  );
}

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", createCard());
```

```css
.grass {
  color: green
}

.fire {
  color: red
}

.water {
  color: blue
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm still getting familiar with .map and other array functions. I didn't realize that .map returned an array of the HTML strings rather that the strings of the original array